# Como obter retorno de uma promise nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Não consigo entender como pegar o retorno de uma promise no JavaScript.
No exemplo abaixo, como obter o retorno de `const info`?

```
const GoogleSpreadSheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const credentials = require('../credenciais.json');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const acessoPlanilha = async() => {
    const planilha = new GoogleSpreadSheet(planilhaID);
    await promisify(planilha.useServiceAccountAuth)(credentials); 
    const info = await promisify(planilha.getInfo)();
    return info;
}

const info = acessoPlanilha();
console.log(info);


//terminal: Promise { <pending> }
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que o restante do código está correto, você precisa apenas esperar que a promessa se cumpra. Quando ela se cumprir seu código será chamado de volta tanto no caso de um sucesso, primeiro parâmetro, como no caso de uma falha, segundo parâmetro.

A documentação, referênciada abaixo, explica da seguinte forma:

```
p.then(quandoRealizada, quandoRejeitada);
```

Logo, no seu caso, pode ser feito assim:

```
info.then(result => console.log(result), err => console.error(err));
```

Este é o [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) da documentação.
Essa [página](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usando_promises) tem vários exemplos de como usar promises.

Comment: Ficaria assim o código?

let resultado;
const info = acessoPlanilha();
info.then(result => resultado = result, err => console.log(err));
console.log(info);
console.log(resultado);